# How to trace one edge of an open path in SVG

Tags: svg

I am trying to make a web page that allows the user to draw lines in an SVG image.  The drawing part is fine, but each line needs to carry a label that fills the width of the line (the lines are 15px wide).

I have tried to use a `<textpath>` referencing the line they drew, but the baseline of the label ends up running down the middle of the line. [Here is a screenshot to show what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsvjP.png)

I have tried various ways to nudge the text over slightly using CSS and properties, but the only success I have had is to use a `transform`, which will often result in the text 'spilling out' if the direction of the line takes a sudden turn.

The other solution I have tried is to generate a second path that runs down one edge of the user-drawn path and using that for the `<textpath>`, but I'm struggling to find a way to translate the user-drawn path points into points that correspond to the rendered edge of the line.

Does anybody know a way to make either one of these methods work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that the *lines need to carry a label that fills the width of the line (the lines are 15px wide)*.
In order to move the text I use `dy="4"`

```css
text{fill:white;stroke:none;font-family:consolas;}
path{stroke-width:15px;fill:none;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="50 150 350 150">
<defs>
<path id="path" d="M70,180Q100,330 195,225Q290,120 380,250"></path>
</defs>
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path" stroke="#000000"></use>

   <text stroke="#000000" font-size="12" dy="4">
      <textPath id="tp" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path" startOffset="30%">
            just some words I wrote
      </textPath>
    </text>
  

</svg>
```

An other option is using `dominant-baseline="middle"`

```css
text{fill:white;stroke:none;font-family:consolas;}
path{stroke-width:15px;fill:none;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="50 150 350 150">
<defs>
<path id="path" d="M70,180Q100,330 195,225Q290,120 380,250" ></path>
</defs>
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path" stroke="#000000"></use>

   <text stroke="#000000" font-size="12" dominant-baseline="middle">
      <textPath id="tp" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path" startOffset="30%">
            just some words I wrote
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

I hope this is what you were asking.

Comment: Thank you, this has helped. I found my problem was that I was trying to nest all the `<textPath>` elements inside one `<text>` element, and Edge (which was the first browser I was using for testing) only applied the `dy` attribute to the first text node. Keeping it to one `<textPath>` per `<text>` keeps it happy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`dy`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TextElementDYAttribute) attribute to move glyphs in a string - either individually or together - in a vertical direction relative to their orientation.

The spec chapter on [`<tspan>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TSpanElement) elements has a lot of practical examples on how to use  the various positioning attributes (dx, dy, rotate); I'd recomend to read it.

```css
path {
    fill:none;
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 15px;
}
text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <path id="p1" d="M 25,60 60,30 H 80 V 120" />
  <text dy="-7.5px">
    <textPath href="#p1">abcdefghijklmn</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response.  I had previously tried the dy attribute, but looking back I think some other code was overriding it. When I saw your demo working it helped me to find the issue. Thanks again.